# Set up a double integral over the region $0\le y\le |x|$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = x^2y + xy^2 $ and let

$$R = \{ (x,y) : |x| \leq 1 , \; \; 0 \leq y \leq |x| \} $$

Want: $\int_R f $

My setting up

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-x}^x f dydx $$

Is this the correct integral that I need to compute?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Your region in not correct. Draw a picture to see how things look like :-) this is so old!!! of a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-x}^x f(x,y)\, dy\,dx&=\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-x}^x (x^2y+xy^2)\, dy\,dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^1 \left[\frac{1}{2}x^2y^2+\frac{1}{3}xy^3\right]_{y=-x}^x\,dx\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\int_{-1}^1 x^4\,dx\\
&=\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^1 x^4\,dx\\
&=\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{5}\left.x^5\right|_{0}^1\\
&=\frac{4}{15}
\end{align}

Comment: This is not fully correct, since $y$ can not take negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y$ does not take negative values:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^x f(x,y)\, dy\,dx+\int_{-1}^0 \int_{0}^{-x} f(x,y)\, dy\,dx
\end{align}

drawing a picture would help ...